# Spark : dataframe - how to properly parallelize the execution

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application that reads from Kafka with a batch interval of 5 minutes

My application stores the input in a DataFrame, and is configured to execute aggregation queries on the dataframe (~ 1000 queries)

Current solution: from the driver I execute a "for loop" on the list of 1000 queries and execute them.

Problem: I have a hundred queries to execute and it takes a huge amount of time for my application.

Is there a way to make this process more faster ?

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        
        messagesFromKafka.foreachRDD((VoidFunction2<JavaRDD<String>, Time>) (rdd, time) -> {
            
            //...
            SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(sparkConf);
            
            // Convert RDD[String]
            JavaRDD<Bean> rddRow = rdd.map((Function<String, Bean>) line -> {

               Bean row = new Bean();
               
               row.setFiled1(line.split(";")[0]);
               row.setFiled2(line.split(";")[1]);
               //..
               return row;

            });
            
            // ...
            Dataset<Bean> ds = spark.createDataFrame(rddRow, Bean.class);
            
            // Prepare List of query ...
            List<String> listQuery = new ArrayList<>();
            listQuery.add("select sum(..)  group by filed1...");
            listQuery.add("select avg (..) group by field2...");
            
            // perform aggregation with key query
            for (String query : listQuery) {
                Dataset<Bean> dsResult = spark.sql(query);
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Does this actually run? In my experience, you cannot create/use SparkSession within `foreachRDD`. Also, why are you trying to use Spark Streaming instead of Structured Streaming, where you already get DataFrame batches out of the box? And what are you hoping to do with a loop over a list of one query, or run the exact same query multiple times over the exact same dataframe? Why would you need to run hundreds of different queries on the same 5 minute chunk of data?

Comment: 1- Yes it works well, this application is already deployed in production and my mission is to optimize it. 2 - Currently I can't migrate it to Structured Streaming, I updated the code to show you that from RDD I create my dataframe. 3 - Yes the goal is to run different aggregation queries every 5 minutes (on a different dataframe). 4 - I receive every 5 minutes 3 million of different records from a kafka topic

Comment: I only ask because `JavaSparkSessionSingleton`  seems like an anti pattern. And I see no reason here that is stopping you from doing what Structured Streaming already does (your map function would be the only change). If you really want to optimize this, I would suggest not using Spark. Dump data into a BI/OLAP database where many queries can be submitted, such as Druid, Apache Pinot, Clickhouse, etc.